# how to retrieve list when stored in keyring in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-keyring

I am storing a list in python keyring. But when I retrieve it, it is converted into unicode

```
import keyring
c=[]
f=[]

c.append("ian")
c.append("ned")
c.append("stark")
print c
a="5555"
keyring.set_password(a,"internal",c)
d= keyring.get_password(a,"internal")
print d[0]
```

**d=unicode: ['harish', 'ravi', 'kisan']**

c=['harish', 'ravi', 'kisan']
The value of d[0] is "[" not "ian"
similarly, d[1] is "i" not "ned".
I want to make d as list similar to c.

Comment: Can you show us what `d` looks like as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). It will interpret a string as Python code, but safely.

Example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> l = ast.literal_eval("['hello', 'goodbye']")
>>> l
['hello', 'goodbye']
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
```

If the string you get can't be interpreted as valid Python, then you will get a `ValueError`. If that's the case, you'll need to show us what your output looks like in order to determine a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Json to parse the output:

```
import json
import keyring
c=[]
f=[]

c.append("ian")
c.append("ned")
c.append("stark")
print c
a="5555"
keyring.set_password(a,"internal",c)
d= json.loads(keyring.get_password(a,"internal"))
print d[0]
```

Comment: d= json.loads(keyring.get_password(a,"internal"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded